# Parse sign up not working properly in Swift 3

Tags: ios, mongodb, heroku, parse-server

I have a parse-server app deployed on Heroku and MongoDB. In my Swift 3 app I set a button called register which runs the sign up function:

```
@IBAction func SignUpBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let user = PFUser()
    user.username = usernameTextField.text
    user.password = passwordTextField.text
    user.email = emailTextField.text
    user["nameandsurname"] = nameandsurnameTextField.text
    user.signUpInBackground {
        (succeeded: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("error")
            self.errorLabel.text = "Please make sure the email has not already been used or try changing the username"
        } else {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signuptohome", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

When I press the button, even if the fields are blank, the button redirects to the home page anyways, letting the user use the app. How can I do I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My logic is as follows which works.  Also make sure you don't have any `Segues` taking place that you slipped in and forgot in your `storyboard`.

```
//this checks 3 fields that they are filled and not empty
     if  passwordTextField.text == "" || emailTxt.text == "" || usernameTextField.text == ""{
            simpleAlert(mess: "You must fill all fields to sign up")
            self.hideHUD()


    } else {
        let user = PFUser()
        user.username = usernameTextField.text
        user.password = passwordTextField.text
        user.email = emailTextField.text

        user.signUpInBackground { (succeeded, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                //success register not lets log him in!!
                PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: self.usernameTextField.text!, password:self.passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                      // Here you can go to your logged in or dashboard page!!
                        self.hideHUD()

                    } else {
                        //failed to log user in
                        self.simpleAlert(mess: "\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                        self.hideHUD()
                    }}
            // ERROR
            } else {
                //This will be the failed to register user
                self.simpleAlert(mess: "\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                self.hideHUD()
        }}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what is going on with the HideHUD statement. Also, where is the success action? I have two viewcontrollers (a login and a sign up one) and then a home screen in which the current user is checked

Comment: @AlessandroThegreg you can remove the HideHud. That just a special HUD i use to show the user that a action is busy and he needs wait. This function signs up the user and then automatically logs him in. So look at my comment where you need to put your segue.

Comment: @AlessandroThegreg let me know if you get stuck, then ill edit it and change it to fit your logic.

Comment: Yuour solution works perfectly as it does not let the user login without any field but it continues to create users with blank field on my database. So it creates the user even if there is no information inserted. @SnakeBlisken

Comment: That was because you still needed to add validation. Ive updated my answer for you. Take a look @AlessandroThegreg

Comment: Thank you you relly helped! I don't know how to thank you enough! I was having serious problems with this! @SnakeBlisken